# filling DIV with referenced image

Tags: html, css, xhtml, background-image

SO I'm trying to recreate this webpage and am working on the style of the div that I will be using 7 times to span the nav bar and am having trouble getting the referenced image to load in.

I will now post my code. I am using style in the page for quick access but will use an external style sheet when I am done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header class="header" id="header" align="middle"> 
<img src="https://s21.postimg.org/luvg05cjb/header.jpg">
</header>

<style>



.Home {

position: absolute;
background-image: url("https://postimg.org/image/vg652px3f/");
background-size: 99px 30px;
left: 290px;
top: 234px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
width: 99px;
height: 30px;

color: black;
}
</style>

<body>


    <div class="Home">Home</div>




<h1></h1>
<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. There is no head tag in the document.
2. You can't simply put `<header>` tags outside of `<body>` element. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp)
3. Style tags should be placed inside `<head>` or `<body>` tag.
4. This is not an image URL >> https://postimg.org/image/vg652px3f/

Comment: While there once was a proposition to allow <style> elements in the body, it didn't make it and they are still only allowed in the head.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using a website address in the background image style, not an actual image.

The image that you may be referring to is actually at the link:

https://s9.postimg.org/mxwoydqkv/menubg.jpg

Edit: If your goal is to show a website inside your website, you should be using an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://postimg.org/image/vg652px3f/"></iframe>
```